# How can I create a ternary tree in SMLNJ?

Tags: sml, smlnj

Right now I have a binary tree modeled in SMLNJ however I want to change this model to where there is a **tree inside of tree inside of tree.** (Ternary Tree)

If you begin with the root of a binary tree.

```
    Binode with an (id1*(binode))  ß- a binary tree
```

Then if that “binode” is located as part of a tuple: 2Dbinode

That tuple has an identifier and that binode with is the root of the binode tree.

```
    2Dbinode (id2* (binode) *2Dbinode)
```

Each of those in turn are part of a 3Dbinode which consists of:

```
    3Dbinode(id3 * (2Dbinode) * 3Dbinode)
```

For ex. 3Dbinode(id3 * (2Dbinode) * 3Dbinode) the root 3Dbinode might contain the following data:

```
    (25, (7, (11)))

    And by adding the nodes (25, (7, (22)))

    (25, (10, (4))), (30, (7, (22)))
```

[3DBinary Tree Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8srjh.png)

Here is SMLNJ code for the 2D binary tree I am modifying.

```
datatype btree =                 Empty |                 Node of int * btree * btree;
 fun AddNode (i:int, Empty) = Node(i, Empty, Empty) |
  AddNode(i:int, Node(j, left, right)) =  
                  if i = j then Node(i, left, right)  
                  else if i < j then Node(j, AddNode(i, left), right) 
                  else Node(j, left, AddNode(i, right)); 
fun printInorder Empty = () |  
                   printInorder (Node(i,left,right)) =        
                   (printInorder left; print(Int.toString i ^ " "); printInorder right);

val x : btree = AddNode(50, Empty);
val x : btree = AddNode(75, x);
val x : btree = AddNode(25, x);
val x : btree = AddNode(72, x);
val x : btree = AddNode(20, x);
val x : btree = AddNode(100, x);
val x : btree = AddNode(3, x);
val x : btree = AddNode(36, x); 
val x : btree = AddNode(17, x);
val x : btree = AddNode(87, x);
printInorder(x);
```

***I need to populate the data structure with N randomized (3Dnodes):***

**How can I implement these functions?**

**Search for a specific node displaying the path to the node ex: (25, 10, 4) the display would be**

- (25)
- (25, 7)
- (25, 10)
- (25, 10,4)

**If the user searches for a node that does not exist:**
(30, (7, (30))) then the path displayed would be

- (25)
- (30)
- (30,7)
- (30, 7, 30) NOT FOUND

**If the user wishes to ADD a node at any level they should be prompted to enter the 3 digit code for that node;  Again the path should be displayed.**

- **EX: ADD (30, 11, 5) then the display would be**

  - (25)
  - (30)
  - (30, 7)
  - (30, 11) created
  - (30, 11, 5) created

**Print out the contents of the 3dbinode tree as a sequence of (A,B,C)
DELETE a node**
Delete a node: EX:  DEL (30, 7, _)
Then the result would be
 - (30, 7, 22) deleted 
 - (30, 7, 0) created

Comment: I have adjusted the original question. Yes you are correct, I am looking for a ternary tree.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ternary tree?

*Edit 2: After you reviewed your question, it still seems unclear how you wish to navigate this ternary tree when searching it. A* binary search tree *divides its elements left and right depending on which one is greater. You have described no similar criterion: **When should your functions use the first, second and third branch?***

*Edit 3: I've provided the function `pathExists` that works on ternary trees, but `AddNode` is still missing as you have not provided any insight into the questions that I've highlighted with bold. If your tree really does serve the purpose of containing points in a 3-dimensional space, it* does *sound like you want a* k-d tree, *as I suggested once. I've also partially provided the function `make3DTree` under the assumption that a k-d tree is what you're looking for.*

---

Until I saw the drawing you made of a [*ternary tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_tree) (or generally an [*n*-ary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree)), I could not understand your question. A ternary tree simply has (up to) three child nodes at each level instead of the binary tree's two.

The wording "tree inside of a tree inside of a tree" means something different than the [*branching factor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_factor) (2, 3, *n*). Exactly how you turn the triples `(25, 7, 11)`, `(25, 7, 22)`, `(25, 10, 4)`, and `(30, 7, 22)` into [your ternary tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8srjh.png) is still a little puzzling to me. It seems that the bottom nodes only have two empty leaves. I will interpret this as if there were a third empty arrow in the middle.

Your `AddNode` function constructs [*binary search trees*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) where the smaller elements go to the left, and the larger elements to the right. **But how, then, do you wish to use a third branch?**

Compare the following generic / integer-specific binary tree datatype definitions,

```
datatype 'a btree = BTreeEmpty | BTreeNode of 'a * 'a btree * 'a btree
datatype int_btree = BTreeEmpty | BtreeNode of 'a * int_btree * int_btree
```

with the ones for ternary trees,

```
datatype 'a ttree = TTreeEmpty | TTreeNode of 'a * 'a ttree * 'a ttree * 'a ttree
datatype int_ttree = TTreeEmpty | TtreeNode of 'a * int_ttree * int_ttree * int_ttree
```

or even ones that support variable branching in each node,

```
datatype 'a tree = TreeEmpty | TreeNode of 'a * 'a tree list
datatype int_tree = TreeEmpty | TreeNode of int * int_tree list
```

Creating the ternary tree you depicted,

```
val treeModel =
    let val t = TTreeNode
        val e = TTreeEmpty
    in
        t (25,
           e,
           t (7,
              e,
              t (11, e, e, e),
              t (10,
                 e,
                 t (4, e, e, e),
                 e
                )
             ),
           t (30,
              e,
              t (7,
                 e,
                 t (22, e, e, e),
                 e
                ),
              e)
          )
    end
```

although it would probably be more convenient with a function like `AddNode`, only you need to specify a consistent way for elements to be added to this kind of tree. **How does the *binary search tree* logic translate to ternary trees?**

---

#### Determining if a path exists in a ternary tree

You can determine if a path to a node exists. Since a tree can have any depth, a path can have any length and should be represented with a list. The path `[25, 7, 10, 4]` exists in [your ternary tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8srjh.png), for example.

```
fun pathExists [] _ = true (* the empty path is trivially found *)
  | pathExists _ TTreeEmpty = false (* no non-empty path goes through an empty tree *)
  | pathExists (x::xs) (TTreeNode (y, subtree1, subtree2, subtree3)) =
    x = y andalso
    (pathExists xs subtree1 orelse
     pathExists xs subtree2 orelse
     pathExists xs subtree3)
```

Testing this function with `treeModel` above:

```
- pathExists [25, 7, 10, 4] treeModel;
> val it = true : bool
- pathExists [25, 30, 7, 22] treeModel;
> val it = true : bool
- pathExists [25, 7, 11, 9] treeModel;
> val it = false : bool
- pathExists [25, 7, 9] treeModel;
> val it = false : bool
```

#### Inserting a point in a ternary tree [???]

A template for this function could be

```
fun AddNode (x, TTreeEmpty) = TTreeNode (x, TTreeEmpty, TTreeEmpty, TTreeEmpty)
  | AddNode (x, TTreeNode (y, subtree1, subtree2, subtree3))) = ???
```

but if `x <> y`, which of the three subtrees should it try to add `x` to?

---

#### K-d tree?

*Edit 1: After having answered, I realize that perhaps you are looking for a* [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)*? A k-d tree can store k-dimensional vectors, **using only binary trees**, in a way that allows efficient, locality-specific lookups.*

The great trick here is to say that the 1st level of the tree divides the space into two halves on the X-axis, the 2nd level of the tree divides the left/right halves into halves on the Y-axis, the 3rd level of the tree divides the left/right halves into halves on the Z-axis, the 4th level on the X-axis again, the 5th level on the Y-axis again, and so on.

Here is an initial translation of that pseudocode for *k = 3* into Standard ML:

```
(* 'byDimension dim (p1, p2)' determines if p1 is greater than p2 in dimension dim. *)
fun byDimension 0 ((x1,_,_), (x2,_,_)) = x1 > x2
  | byDimension 1 ((_,y1,_), (_,y2,_)) = y1 > y2
  | byDimension 2 ((_,_,z1), (_,_,z2)) = z1 > z2
  | byDimension d _ _ = raise Fail ("Invalid dimension " ^ Int.toString d)

(* split points into two halves and isolate the middle element *)
fun splitAt dim points = ...

(* The number of dimensions, matching the arity of the point tuples below *)
val k = 3

fun make3DTree ([], _) = BTreeEmpty
  | make3DTree (points, depth) =
    let val axis = depth mod k
        val len = List.length points
        val points_sorted = ListMergeSort.sort (byDimension axis) points
        val (points_left, median, points_right) = splitAt len points_sorted
    in BTreeNode (median,
                  make3DTree (points_left, depth+1),
                  make3DTree (points_right, depth+1))
    end
```

One optimization could be to reduce the constant re-sorting.

Adding a single 3D point to this tree is well-defined, but does not guarantee that the tree is particularly balanced:

```
(* get the (n mod 3)-th value of a 3-tuple. *)
fun getDimValue (n, (x,y,z)) =
    let val m = n mod k
    in if m = 0 then x else
       if m = 1 then y else
       if m = 2 then z else
       raise Fail ("Invalid dimension " ^ Int.toString n)
    end

(* the smallest tree that contains a k-dimensional point
 * has depth k-1 (because of 0-indexing). *)
fun deepEnough depth = depth >= k-1

fun insertNode (point, BTreeEmpty, depth) =
    let val v1 = getDimValue (depth, point)
        val v2 = getDimValue (depth+1, point)
        val (left, right) =
            if deepEnough depth
            then (BTreeEmpty, BTreeEmpty)
            else if v1 > v2
                 then (insertNode (point, BTreeEmpty, depth+1), BTreeEmpty)
                 else (BTreeEmpty, insertNode (point, BTreeEmpty, depth+1))
    in BTreeNode (v1, left, right)
    end
  | insertNode (point, BTreeNode (v1, left, right), depth) =
    let val v2 = getDimValue (depth, point)
    in if v1 > v2
       then BTreeNode (v1, insertNode (point, left, depth+1), right)
       else BTreeNode (v1, left, insertNode (point, right, depth+1))
    end
```

Determining if a point exists in this tree can be achieved by performing a *nearest-neighbor search*, which is slightly less trivial to implement.

Comment: Yes each node should have three children: left, middle and right.

Comment: You have answered very little.

Comment: Sorry, I have elaborated in my original question above. I think that will put it in better context of what I am trying accomplish.

Comment: And yes sorry my english is not too good. I mean ternary tree when I say 3d tree.